# How to include internal dependencies in a Maven project using JavaCompiler API?

Tags: java, maven, linker-errors, java-compiler-api, javacompiler

I am using *JavaCompiler* API to compile a string representation of an existing java class in a Maven project.
Yet, I'm getting a linker error due to internal dependencies and I'm not sure how to include internal dependencies in the compilation task.

Here's the code snippet:

```
String importedClasses = "/Users/XXXX/Desktop/defects4j/project_repos/gson/gson/target/classes/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.class";
List<String> dependencies = new ArrayList<>();
dependencies.add("com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken");

JavaFileObject file = new JavaSourceFromString(this.className, writer.toString());
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(file);
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, null, diagnostics, Arrays.asList("-classpath", "/Users/XXXX/Desktop/defects4j/project_repos/gson/gson/target/classes/", "-d", outputDir, "-cp", importedClasses), dependencies, compilationUnits);
boolean success = task.call();
```

Comment: Are you referring to  [Java SE JavaCompiler](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~mcpc/Java_Docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)? Or Mavens JavaCompiler Mojo?
Are you writing your a maven plugin or how do your expect to get parameters from maven?

Comment: Can you explain in detail what kind of problem you are trying to solve? Why not let Maven Compiler PLugin compile your code?

Comment: I want to make a Maven project that, programmatically, compiles the test classes of another Maven project. I wasn't aware of CompilerMojo, and even after discovering it, I'm unable to compile another project from its path.